# method() in x.y.z is defined in an inaccessible class or interface

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

**Super.java**

```
package x.y.z;

public abstract class Super {
  public CustomClass a() {
    return new CustomClass();
  }

  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

**Sub.java**

```
package x.y.z;

public abstract class Sub extends Super {
  public String getDescription() {
    return "Is a Sub";
  }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package x.y.z;

public class User {
  private class UseCase extends Sub {
    public String getName() {
      return "UseCase";
    }
  }

  public UseCase use() {
    return new UseCase();
  }
}
```

In another part of my app I try to access `new User().use().a()`, and I think this causes the error (it's a compile-time error though).

---

Trying to compile the above errors:

```
a() in x.y.z.Super is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
```

What's causing this error and how do I fix it?

---

**New question**

This makes the error disappear for me:

**User.java**

```
package x.y.z;

public class User {
  private class UseCase extends Sub {
    public String getName() {
      return "UseCase";
    }
  }

  public Super use() {
    return new UseCase();
  }
}
```

Changing the type of `User.use()` to `Super` "fixes" the error.

Is this a problematic "fix", or will this work fine without any hiccups?

Comment: Not sure, but returning a private inner class from a public method is probably not a good idea.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  It compiles normally for me, and I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: @JacobG. the error actually comes when I try to access `new User().use().a()` elsewhere, and I'm building with maven

Comment: Regarding your fix, if you add a new method to Sub or UseCase it will not be visible without casting first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a() in x.y.z.Super is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
```

Because a `UseCase` class, that you are trying to return, is private. Consider the following example, that compiles without errors:

```
User user = new User();
Sub sub = user.use(); // because of implicit up-casting to Sub (and Sub is public)
sub.a();
```

If you want to fit these 3 lines into a single expression, you need an explicit cast:

```
CustomClass custom = ((Sub) new User().use()).a();
```

Also, as you've already pointed out, you can change the `use(...)` method return type to a `Sub` or a `Super` class, so the following code will work without additional casts:

```
CustomClass custom = new User().use().a();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the type that you return from `User#use` (i.e. `UseCase`) is `private` to the `User` class, prohibiting it from being accessed from anywhere outside `User`.  Modifying `UseCase` to be `public` instead of `private` should fix your issue.

```
public class UseCase extends Sub {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "UseCase";
    }
}
```